# Object syntax for Youtube loadVideoById does not work ( tested on iOS devices)

Tags: youtube-api

Note! it does not work on iOS devices like the iPad

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById

The object syntax of loadVideoById seems not to work, I get an error that the video is not available. Any thoughts or ideas?

**Argument syntax**

```
 player.loadVideoById(videoId:String, startSeconds:Number, suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

**Object syntax**

```
player.loadVideoById({videoId:String, startSeconds:Number, endSeconds:Number, suggestedQuality:String}):Void
```

see example link here;
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13780885/loadvideobyid/index.html

Comment: Can you post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: ok, I added example link

Answer (score 0):

This is being tracked at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3937

(In general, that issue tracker is a more appropriate place to report bugs with the API than Stack Overflow.)